# Can not find the class of "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.AggregationClient" in hbase 0.96 .0

Tags: hbase

I can find it's apidocs at http://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/coprocessor/AggregationClient.html , but can not find it in hbase-0.96.0-src.tar.gz or hbase-0.96.0-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz , also can not find it in hbase-0.95.2 .

Is there some changes？

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This Class `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.AggregationClient` is present in [hbase-client-0.95.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/hbase/hbase-client-0.95.0.jar.zip)

Comment: In hbase 0.96, use CoprocessorService instead of CoprocessorProtocol. Thanks!